# using ctypes methods in python gives unexpected error

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm pretty new to python and ctypes. I'm trying to accomplish a seemingly easy task but am getting unexpected results.  I'm trying to pass a string to a c function so I'm using the c_char_p type but it's giving me an error message.  To simply it, this is whats happening:

```
>>>from ctypes import *
>>>c_char_p("hello world") 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string or integer address expected instead of str instance
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.5, ctypes: TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888565/python-3-5-ctypes-typeerror-bytes-or-integer-address-expected-instead-of-str)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 3.x, the `"text literal"` is really a unicode object. You want to use the byte-string literal like `b"byte-string literal"`

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> c_char_p('hello world')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string or integer address expected instead of str instance
>>> c_char_p(b'hello world')
c_char_p(b'hello world')
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you this helps very much. Turns out I was looking at python 2.7 documentation which is why I was so confused.