# Python 3 TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to get Python 2 code to run on Python 3, and this line

```
    argv = (c_char_p * len(args))(*args)
```

causes this error

```
File "/Users/hanxue/Code/Python/gsfs/src/gsfs.py", line 381, in main
  fuse = FUSE(GoogleStorageFUSE(username, password, logfile=logfile), mount_point, **fuse_args)
File "/Users/hanxue/Code/Python/gsfs/src/fuse.py", line 205, in __init__
  argv = (c_char_p * len(args))(*args)
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
```

This is the full method

```
class FUSE(object):
    """This class is the lower level interface and should not be subclassed
       under normal use. Its methods are called by fuse"""

    def __init__(self, operations, mountpoint, raw_fi=False, **kwargs):
        """Setting raw_fi to True will cause FUSE to pass the fuse_file_info
               class as is to Operations, instead of just the fh field.
               This gives you access to direct_io, keep_cache, etc."""

        self.operations = operations
        self.raw_fi = raw_fi
        args = ['fuse']
        if kwargs.pop('foreground', False):
            args.append('-f')
        if kwargs.pop('debug', False):
            args.append('-d')
        if kwargs.pop('nothreads', False):
            args.append('-s')
        kwargs.setdefault('fsname', operations.__class__.__name__)
        args.append('-o')
        args.append(','.join(key if val == True else '%s=%s' % (key, val)
                             for key, val in kwargs.items()))
        args.append(mountpoint)

        argv = (c_char_p * len(args))(*args)
```

Which is invoked by this line

```
fuse = FUSE(GoogleStorageFUSE(username, password, logfile=logfile), mount_point, **fuse_args)
```

How do I avoid the error by changing the args into `byte[]`?

Comment: maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480376/using-ctypes-methods-in-python-gives-unexpected-error

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 all string literals are, by default, unicode.  So the phrases `'fuse'`, `'-f'`, `'-d'`, etc, all create `str` instances.  In order to get `bytes` instances instead you will need to do both:

- pass bytes into the FUSE  (`username`, `password`, `logfile`, `mount_point`, and each arg in `fuse_args`
- change all the string literals in FUSE itself to be bytes:  `b'fuse'`, `b'-f'`, `b'-d'`, etc.

This is not a small job.