# Ctypes: passing string as argument from Python to C

Tags: python, c++, pointers, ctypes

Anyone familiar with Ctypes who can help me?

I am trying to call a C function (actually a class method) from python. My issue is passing a string as argument. To keep it short, I wont copy the C code, because everything works fine there. But here is my python class:

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p
clib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

class Session(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = clib.tunnel_init()

    def start(self, user_input):
        clib.tunnel_start.restype = c_char_p
        clib.tunnel_start.argtypes = [c_char_p]
        a = c_char_p(user_input)
        result = clib.tunnel_start(self.obj, a)
        return str(result)
```

When I run:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello = Session()
    msg = hello.start("test")
    print(msg)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
```

Seems like my argument is treated like a string, not as a pointer. How can I fix it?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888565/python-3-5-ctypes-typeerror-bytes-or-integer-address-expected-instead-of-str and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873437/python-3-typeerror-bytes-or-integer-address-expected-instead-of-str-instance

Comment: C does not support _methods_ or classes it is a different language than C++.