# Python 3.5, ctypes: TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm having an issue with ctypes. I think my type conversion is correct and the error isn't making sense to me. 
Error on line " arg - ct.c_char_p(logfilepath) "
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance

I tried in both python 3.5 and 3.4.

function i'm calling:

```
stream_initialize('stream_log.txt')
```

Stream_initialize code"

```
def stream_initialize(logfilepath):
    f = shim.stream_initialize
    arg = ct.c_char_p(logfilepath)
    result = f(arg)

    if result:
        print(find_shim_error(result))
```

Comment: That last line's going to fail in Python 3 - `print` is a function and requires parentheses.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`c_char_p` takes `bytes` object so you have to convert your `string` to `bytes` first:

```
ct.c_char_p(logfilepath.encode('utf-8'))
```

Another solution is using the `c_wchar_p` type which takes a `string`.

Comment: This response should really be in the documentation on ctypes. I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Comment: Then why there documentation didn't mentioned this https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

Comment: That's because you're looking at the python2 documentation. Replace the "2" in your url with "3" and you'll actually find that the python3 doc states that it needs bytes.

Answer (score 2):

*For completeness' sake*:
It is also possible to call it as `stream_initialize(b'stream_log.txt')`. Note the `b` in front of the string, which causes it to be interpreted as a `bytes` object.