# using Structure and char array in python

Tags: python

I am using ctype. And I want use Structure as Argument.here is my code:

```
Time="AuditSuccess"
class SecurityVarToCdll(Structure):
   _fields_ = [("Time",c_char_p),("EventID",c_char_p),("Keyword",c_char_p),("Level",c_int),("User",c_char_p)]
Var=SecurityVarToCdll()
Var.Time=c_type_p(Time)
```

then I get the following:

```
 Var.Time = c_char_p(Time)
 TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
```

I am a freshman here.
Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: What is your `Time` variable, the one you use in the expression `c_char_p(Time)`?

Comment: What research have you done?  Is the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888565/python-3-5-ctypes-typeerror-bytes-or-integer-address-expected-instead-of-str) not helpful?  Also, I'd recommend a [mcve] as the code snippet does not fully encapsulate the issue (IE: `Time` is not defined).

Answer (score 2):

In Python, strings are enclosed in quotes like so:

```
 string = "this is a string"
```

That is what you have, when you need bytes.
Bytes are defined like so:

```
bytes = b'this is a bytes object'
```

or

```
bytes = b"This is another bytes object"
```

It looks like you need to use bytes - so putting 'b' before your quotes.

Comment: wow, Thanks very much. I have forgotten that python uses Unicode encoding by default. That really works.